# Can LED be controlled using PWM pin without using a FET in LT3475?

Tags: led

I am designing a LED driver circuit using LT3475EFE-1#PBF IC for controlling two LEDS. I have a  signal from an I/O pin for LED ON-OFF control which is tied to PWM input (as recommended). Typical circuits tie an NFET to the cathode of LED and the gate is controlled by PWM input.

Can I connect my control signal to PWM pin and perform LED lighting without using a NFET? I don't want to achieve LED dimming control, just switching action is enough.

Any help would be appreciated as I need to design the circuit in mass scale.

[image: LED control circuit]

Answer (score 2):

According to the LT3475 [data sheet](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linear.com%2Fdocs%2F14958&ei=L_xMU9vyBpDT7AaNwoGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNGOq94ztdg2spA33YaDXWY6yaQUXw&bvm=bv.64764171,d.ZGU): -

> For PWM dimming ratios of 20 to 1 or less, the NFET can be omitted

This means use it in its normal mode of operation but if you require a wider control over the dimming then use a FET. Normal mode: -

[image]

Comment: What does "ratio of 20 : 1" mean in terms of pwm?

Comment: @passerby I think its residual cap voltage keeping the led slightly powered ie you can't dim it below one twentieth of full brightness.

Comment: hi Andy...you are correct...The FET can be avoided in normal mode of operation.But i need to control LED through ON-OFF signal input to PWM pin without a NFET. I don't require  dimming of LEDs.

Comment: @user40383 I'm no expert on this chip, but if it is residual charge keeping the LED glowing then maybe a forward-biased diode in series with the LED might persuade it to glow less when the PWM pin is deactivated?